# 'Property 'XX' does not exist on type' useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have an API call that returns a response which I add to state with setInfo:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([])

axios.post('/user', {
  data: 'data'
})
.then(response => {
  setInfo(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

When I destructor the response I get the following warning from Typescript:

```
const { propertyOne } = info
Property 'propertyOne' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

Adding the property or 'info' to the Interface does not solve this, I'm not sure what I need to do here?

Comment: You are trying to access an object's property on an array. Initialize `info` state to an object `useState({})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define type for info state, try this

```
type InfoType = {
   propertyOne: any;
}
const [info, setInfo] = useState<InfoType[]>([]);
const { propertyOne } = info[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the following error on the empty array one useState:

'Argument of type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ propertyOne: string; } | (() => { propertyOne: string; })'.
  Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '() => { propertyOne: string; }'.
    Type 'undefined[]' provides no match for the signature '(): { propertyOne: string; }'.'

Comment: If your Info is an array, so you can not `const { propertyOne } = info`, its must be `const { propertyOne } = info[0]` i updated answer

Answer (score 0):

## Fix

Change:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
```

To something that has `propertyInfo` e.g.:

```
 const [info, setInfo] = useState<{propertyOne: any}({propertyOne: null});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, I get the following:
"This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ propertyOne: any; }' has no call signatures."